# Distribute yearly numbers over months exponentially

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

so I have got **yearly production numbers** such as,

```
Year          2017  2018    2019    2020    2021    2022
Production    1489  12378   35352   69521   116737  174831
```

next I would like to **distribute** them **over** the **months** of the years in a way that they grow exponentially. For **example, year 2017** could look something like this:

```
Month                  Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun,    Jul,    Aug,    Sep,    Oct,    Nov,    Dec
Increment Production    20, 40,  59,  79,  98,  116,    135,    153,    171,    189,    206,    224
Total Production        20, 60,  119, 198, 295, 412,    546,    699,    870,    1059,   1265,   1489
```

Please note that the total production at the end of December 2017 is equal to the yearly production I started with (first table).

Now, I don't care what the precise number in any month is but I do care about two things:

1. That the numbers within a year are always growing from month to month and that the sum of all months in a year equal the yearly production target.
2. That the numbers are also growing year over year based of the above yearly numbers.

**What I have tried so far:**
Within Excel, I used the Expon.Dist function to calculate a factor for each month of each year such that the sum of factors of any year yield one. That is, I played with the numbers and found with an x=0.013555749 and a lambda equal to the month (1 through 12) of the year. Subsequently, I multiplied each month's factor to the yearly production to yield the respective monthly production number. The following are the formula and factors I derived.

```
EXPON.DIST(0.013554749,MONTH(Date),1)


Month   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sept  Oct   Nov  Dec    Sum of Factor
Factor  0.01  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.07  0.08  0.09  0.10  0.11  0.13  0.14  0.15  1.00
```

Please note that the factors are growing from month to month and equal one when summed up.

**My Problem:**
This only solves the first of my priorities but not the second. The above monthly production numbers are calculated using this factor and grow month over month. However, year over year I have big drops from December of one year to the first months of the following year. For example, the monthly production for January 2018 using this factor would be 167 which is smaller than the 224 of production in December 2017. This gap obviously widens with growing absolute yearly production numbers.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to derive a factor that is applied to the yearly production numbers such that the numbers within a year grow month over month AND having no drop from the end of one year to the beginning of the next?

Thanks, and please let me know if I have expressed myself comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

My "simple" solution is this.

Since there are 12 months I would divide the total on number of months then create a factor that adds up to 12.

In this pic you can see that for your first value

[image: cell B6]

then for the next case, 2018, its like this

[image: still cell B6]

My test then looks like this, as you can see the factor adds up to 12 and the total always ends up like the total value

[image: total test]

Comment: Hey krib, thanks for your reply. While your curve is smoother than mine (which is great!) I think your method still doesn't solve the problem mentioned in 2. entirely. For example, for December 2020 I get 8,690 while for January 2021 I get 5,059. So there still is a drop on the year's change. Any ideas?

Comment: you can change the factors, but this aint foolproof for sure.

I changed them to

`0,92 jan ->1,1 okt ~ 1,12 nov 1,14 dec`

that helpes